# How to extract few fields from a string?

Tags: php

I am working on website in which I want to extract few fields from a string. The code which I have used to get that string is:

```
<?php 
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->logistic_out); $i++) {
    echo strtolower($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_times);

   }
?>
```

The above echo code is printing the following string which is `logistics_times`:

```
a: 7: {
    s: 3: "mon";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "tue";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "wed";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "thu";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "fri";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sat";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sun";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the above php code so that it extracts below information by parsing above string:

```
mon 09:00   21:00
tue 09:00   21:00
wed 09:00   21:00
thu 09:00   21:00
fri 09:00   21:00
sat 09:00   21:00
```

Comment: That looks like a serialized string, checkout [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Str_replace() to remove space from string & use unserialize() to convert data into array:**

```
$str = 'a: 7: {s: 3: "mon";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "tue";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "wed";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "thu";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "fri";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "sat";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}s: 3: "sun";a: 2: {s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";}}';

$data = unserialize(str_replace(' ', '', $str));

foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key." ".$value['start']." ".$value['end']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: what changes I should make in the code above to get the times as shown in the problem statement above ?

Comment: @flash Use unserialize()